# Difference between Data Type and Object

Tags: java, object, types, terminology

I am new to JAVA and would like to ask what is the difference between data type and object. To be specific, I would like to ask what is the difference between data type (float) and object (Float) ? 
What is the advantage of using object Float, instead of type float?
Can you give me some examples?

In addition, what is the advantage of using type float, instead of object Float?

Moreover, can I store multiple float values into object Float?

Comment: Google for `Wrapper classes in Java`.

Comment: This has (right now at least) 2 upvotes and I'm not sure which part of the question shows research effort.

Comment: You can find the answers to all of these questions by READING the Oracle Java Tutorial, or any decent Java text book.  StackOverflow should not be treated as a personal research assistant / tutor.

Answer (score 3):

Float is a wrapper class. Wrapper classes are generally used to represent a primitive type (In Java primitive types are byte, int, float, etc.) when an Object is required. All of the wrapper classes inherit from the Number class.

The advantage of using a wrapper object like Float is that in some cases you will be able to use `Float` where you couldn't use `float`. For instance Lists such as an ArrayList can only hold reference types (i.e. objects, not primitives).

You can go:

```
ArrayList<Float>....
```

but using

```
ArrayList<float>....
```

won't work and will result in a syntax error.

Oracle has a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) on this

Comment: Do you mean object Float is much better than data type float?
So float is unnecessary? And all float can be replaced by object Float?

Comment: Please don't attempt to answer this.  You can't do an adequate job, and the OP obviously hasn't done any research.  He doesn't *deserve* the effort you have already put into this ...

Comment: @CHANist To understand the differences and the pros/cons of each you need to understand how differently primitive data types and objects are handled by the compiler/JVM . This can't really be answered in an SO answer.